# Why Activity is restarting ? How to avoid it?

Tags: android, android-activity, restart

There are several threads running on the keywords "Activity restart". 
Honestly, I did my best before posting here.

In my application a background service monitors sensors (even when screen is OFF) and launches an activity. In order to Turn On the screen and show activity on lock screen am setting following flags

```
int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON   |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.flags |= flags;
```

Everything goes perfect, Screen turns on, Activity displayed on lockscreen. But Activity is restarting. I do not know why ?
This activity orientation is set to portrait. So change in orientation configuration should not restart activity. I could not find the reason for restart. What else might be the reason for restart ?

To avoid restarting I also set android:configChanges (to find the reason I included all possible configuration changes

```
  <activity android:label="@string/tstActivity_label" 
              android:name=".TstActivity" 
              android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
              android:noHistory="true" 
              android:excludeFromRecents="true" 
              android:configChanges="locale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|
                                     navigation|orientation|screenLayout|
                                     screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection" >

    </activity>
```

Still no positive signs, activity restarts. Also onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) is never called.

Could some one help me how to find the reason for restart and how to avoid it ?

Why android:configChanges is being ignored.

Tested with API levels 14 and 15.

My main problem I am doing some actions in onStop() that should be only done when the activity is really stopping and not while it is restarting.

Thank you.

Note: I also tried with wakelocks and keygaurd manager, same story Activity is restarting.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "Activity is restarting"? I mean, if you launch an Activity from a Service, it's the first time it is shown, how can it *restart*?

Comment: Can you show the code where you start the Activity from your service.?

Comment: Hi, Here is how the activity is launched from service   `Intent StrAct = new Intent(this, TstActivity.class);
    StrAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(StrAct);`

Comment: @m0skit0 The activity displayes but the life cycle is like this   onCreat > onStarted > onResume > onPause > onStopped > onRestart > onStart > onResume ..  Which means the Activity is started, stopped and restarted.

Comment: I used a log statements in every life cycle methods to trace it.

Comment: what if the sensor condition is always true, the service will obvious restart the activity.

Comment: @twntee After launching the Activity, I am killing the Service too. This was working fine until Android 2.3.6. Now am upgrading to 4.3 and found this problem.

Comment: Hi, Am still struggling with this problem, please give me your suggestions .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The activity is not being "recreated", it is only being "restarted". This is a normal part of the activity lifecycle. If the activity was being recreated due to a config change, you would also see `onDestroy()` and `onCreate()` being called again. This is clearly not the case.

There is no configuration change going on here, which is why `onConfigurationChanged()` is not being called.

I think what is happening has to do with the fact that the screen is off/locked when your activity is launched. The activity is created and resumed, but then Android notices that the screen is off/locked, so it pauses the activity. Then it realizes that the activity should be shown, so it resumes the activity. I'm not able to test this case exactly right now, but I'm sure that I've seen similar behaviour in my own apps when we launch an activity while the screen is off.

Your app should be able to deal with multiple calls to `onStart()`, `onStop()`, `onRestart()`, `onPause()` and `onResume()` without getting confused. If not, you'll need to fix that.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. Exactly this is the problem. Am stuck while handling multiple calls to onStart(), onStop(), onRestart(), onPause() and onResume().   In this activity, I start a music in onCreat() and stop it when user reacts to UI or the activity goes to background (user presses home button). So I have to stop the music in onStop() unfortunately now onStop() executes twice. I am stuck to identify the call to onStop() when the activity is really going to background. So now Music starts and stops immediately. Could you please give me some suggestions on how to handle this situation ?

Comment: If you are seeing multiple calls to `onStop()` within a short period of time, you could try the following: in `onStop()` start a new `Thread` that sleeps for a few seconds. After the sleep completes the thread should stop the music. If, while the thread is sleeping, `onStart()` is called, you should tell the thread to quit. You can do this by setting a boolean flag for the thread and then calling `interrupt()` on the thread. The thread should catch `InterruptedException` and check the boolean to decide if it should stop the music or just quit.

Comment: Thank you very much for the inputs. I will try this solution. Mean while I got one more idea, my idea is when the activity is launched I use a handler and post a message with a delay. With in this delay I assume the activity will be paused and then resumed. After this delay I will do the actual task(start music) of my activity. I will try both the solutions. Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler. During onCreat() send a message to Handler with a delay of say 100 ms. With this time my activity goes paused and resumed again. Now when the message in received by the handler, start the actual functionality. In my case when the message is received, I start the music and in onStop() with out any condition, stop the music.